# How to generalize type parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I have a list of Pairs that I'm calling groupBy on. However, groupBy includes both parts of the pair in the values, and I only want to include the part of the pair which was not "grouped by".

```
List(1->2, 1->3, 2->3) groupBy (_._1)
```

> scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(Int, Int)]] = Map(1 ->
>   List((1,2), (1,3)), 2 -> List((2,3)))

I wrote a method to map over the Map entries and remove the dupe keys:

```
def removeDupeKeyFromPair[A, B](m: Map[A, List[Pair[A, B]]]): Map[A, List[B]] =
  m map { case(k, vlist) => k -> { vlist map { case(dupe, b) => b } } }
```

However, I would like to generalize this from `List[Pair[A,B]]` to `C[Pair[A,B]]` where `C<:Iterable`, so I tried

```
def removeDupeKeyFromPair[A, B, C[Pair[A, B]] <: Iterable[Pair[A, B]]]
                         (m: Map[A, C[Pair[A, B]]]): Map[A, C[B]]
```

but this produced

> error: B takes no type parameters, expected: two

How do I express these types properly?

**Edit:**
This is a learning exercise for me, so I'm more interested in how to express the given types properly than I am in finding another solution. Although learning about other solutions is great too.

Comment: The reason for the (admittedly confusing) diagnostic is that you're requiring `C` to take a `Pair[A, B]` type parameter and later refer to `C[B]`, which then causes the compiler to see an inconsistency between the formal `B` (not itself a type constructor) and the reference to `B` in the argument position of `C[B]`. If that's clear...

Comment: C is a formal generic parameter, a generic container of *anything*: ` C[X] <: Iterable[X]`. X is a formal parameter, a placeholder. Then the function accepts C[some actual type] and returns C[some other type] (you fill the placeholder in 2 different ways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make things like these more generic you can use specialized type classes. The one used for methods like `map` and `flatMap` is `FilterMonadic`.

`FilterMonadic` specifies it's map methods as using a `CanBuildFrom`. Most built-in collection classes have one of those available. You can then use it like this:

```
def removeDupeKeyFromPair[A, B, 
  // Define a type C that has type arguments and extends FilterMonadic
  C[X] <: FilterMonadic[X, C[X]], 
  // Define the type that will be returned (provided by the implicit CanBuildFrom)
  That](
    // Use C instead of List    
    m: Map[A, C[(A, B)]])(
      // Define the CanBuildFrom that is required by the map method
      implicit bf:CanBuildFrom[C[(A, B)], B, That]): Map[A, That] =

        // actual logic
        m.map { case (k, vlist) =>
          k -> vlist.map { case (dupe, b) => b }
        }
```

### Edit

Note that I used the `(A, B)` notation instead of `Pair[A, B]`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to change the `Map` values, you can use `mapValues`:

```
scala> List(1->2, 1->3, 2->3) groupBy (_._1) mapValues (_.map(_._2))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(2 -> List(3), 1 -> List(2, 3))
```

Or in a slightly more readable way:

```
scala> List(1->2, 1->3, 2->3) groupBy (_._1) mapValues (lst => lst.map { case(_ ,b) => b })
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(2 -> List(3), 1 -> List(2, 3))
```

Comment: That's definitely useful, thanks for introducing me to mapValues. It looks equivalent to the map statement I wrote above, ignoring the key and mapping over the List values. If you were to write the anonymous function you passed to mapValues as a named function instead, how would you express the type parameters?

Answer (score 1):

What is the point in using `C<:Iterable`?

If you define:

```
def removeDupeKeyFromPair[A,B](m: Map[A, Iterable[(A,B)]]) : Map[A, Iterable[B]]=
      m map { case(k, vlist) => k -> { vlist map { case(dupe, b) => b } } }
```

and invoke that method on a list, it will return a `Map[A, List[B]]`. This is due to the `Builder` mechanism in scala collections.